# Following/Seeking a Moving Position with Velocity & Sin/Cos

Tags: trigonometry, graph-theory, vectors, physics

So basically I am writing a 2D game and ran into a mathematical issue implementing a really simple "seeking" projectile, where it chases the player (who can move).

The projectile acts as follows every update (120 times a second):

- Set its velocity based on its speed and angle relative to the target (player).

  - The **velocity** is calculated by **x = speed * cos(angle)** and **y = speed * sin(angle)**, where **angle between projectile and target** is calculated with **atan2(targetX - projectileX, targetY - projectileY) * 180 / PI**.
- Add the velocity to the projectile's current position **(velocityX + posX, velocityY + posY)**.

**It works as intended ONLY when the player is sitting still**. When the player starts moving around, the projectile is basically sitting in place when translating horizontally/vertically relative to it. The projectile looks like it is "bouncing" up or staying "in place" when moving left/right rapidly, or if you move around it in a circle it stays in place - despite its magnitude being the same, expected projectile speed every instant.

Am I calculating something wrong, or am I doing something wrong logically here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't specify what language you are using, but `atan2` almost universally takes the $y$ coordinate first and the $x$ coordinate second, and then why are you converting that out of radians and into degrees? I hope to goodness you are not using the angle in degrees in `sin` and `cos`. I don't know of any computer language which uses degrees for those functions.

> Am I calculating something wrong, or am I doing something wrong logically here?

You must be mustn't you? If you weren't calculating something wrong or doing something wrong logically you wouldn't have a problem.

Comment: Oh my gosh lol, no wonder! You are right - sin and cos for Java take the angle in radians. For convenience I wanted to convert the angle to degrees from atan2 so I can print it out in a more readable way. Thanks for pointing that out - let me fix that and see if it will work as intended :)

Comment: Yep, I updated/adjusted it so everything is radians besides when I print it out. I mistakenly made it so that it was in degrees with my getAngle(origin, target) function that is passed into sin/cos (which take radians). Thanks for the help.

Comment: OK great good luck with your game!

Answer (score 1):

You might have a better time if you avoid the trig functions altogether.

Let $\Delta x = \mathbf{targetX} - \mathbf{projectileX}.$
Let $\Delta y = \mathbf{targetY} - \mathbf{projectileY}.$
Let $\Delta s = \sqrt{(\Delta x)^2 + (\Delta y)^2}.$

Then set
$$\mathbf{velocityX} = \mathbf{speed} \times \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta s}$$
and  set
$$\mathbf{velocityY} = \mathbf{speed} \times \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta s}.$$

The trick here is that $\operatorname{atan2}(\Delta y, \Delta x)$
returns an angle $\theta$ in radians such that
$$ \cos(\theta) = \frac{\Delta x}{\sqrt{(\Delta x)^2 + (\Delta y)^2}} \tag1 $$
and
$$ \sin(\theta) = \frac{\Delta y}{\sqrt{(\Delta x)^2 + (\Delta y)^2}}, \tag2$$

so essentially all you are doing with the three trig functions
(in the corrected version of the code)
is to go from $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$
to the right-hand sides of Equations $(1)$ and $(2)$.
And you can do that directly just by computing the square root
and dividing, skipping the steps involving $\theta$.

Comment: I appreciate the reply, I'll look into this when I can. It definitely seems more efficient than me using atan2 and whatnot. Thanks.